# Highlight GridView row when a condition is met

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

I'm using `VS2005 C# Server-side` coding.

I'm curious to know that in `VS2005 version`, is it possible to `highlight` a row in a GridView when a condition is met? E.g. If column **Risk** is stored as **high** in the database for that specific row, the row will be `highlighted in Red`.

Is it possible?

---

**Edit:**

Current code:

```
protected void GridView1_OnRowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    // do your stuffs here, for example if column risk is your third column:
    if (e.Row.Cells[3].Text == "H")
    {
        e.Row.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
}
```

I assume column cell starts from 0, so mine is at cell 3. But the color still does not change.

Anyone has any idea?

Comment: No, OnDataBound only gets fired once which isn't what you want. Does it show any error when you try OnRowDataBound?

Comment: Make sure your 'GridView_OnRowDataBound' method is set to 'public'.

Comment: @RUiHAO check my solution, i think the `.Text` would be more applicable in the DataBound event rather than `RowDataBound` since the value is actually contained by a control and not the cell so `DataBinder.Eval` should work for you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, add `OnRowDataBound="yourGridview_RowDataBound"` to your gridview. This event gets triggered for every gridview row.

In the code behind, have this:

```
public void yourGridview_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        // do your stuffs here, for example if column risk is your third column:
        if (e.Row.Cells[2].Text == "high")
        {
            e.Row.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check your e.Row.Cells[3].Text is really equal to "High" (correct cases, no extra spaces, etc). You can use Response.Write("-" + e.Row.Cells[3].Text + "-") to display the values.

Comment: It is correct, at the top of my page is full of the text in my third column.

Comment: Try temporarily disable "if (e.Row.Cells[3].Text == "H") { }" and just leave out "e.Row.BackColor = Color.Red;". Does the color change now?

Comment: Yes it does, the whole table turns red.

Comment: Then it means "if (e.Row.Cells[3].Text == "H")" never returns true. I can't see your data so cannot tell why they don't match up but you should be able to identify any difference between the two.

Answer (score 3):

Use RowDataBound Event. In this event you would get to add the css based upon your condition

```
 void GridView_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
  {

    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
      // Logic for High
      if(e.Row.Cells[1].Text > 100)
      //set color
      e.Row.Attributes.Add("style", "this.style.backgroundColor = '#FFFFFF';");

    }

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should subscribe for the `RowDataBound` event of the grid and catch hold of the row which has your column mentioning Risk as High then set the `BackColor` of the row to your highlighting color choice

```
 If (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
 {
        //DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem,"Risk"))
        //if this is high then set the color
        e.Row.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Yellow
 }
```

MSDN [Formatting the GridView Based on the Underlying Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479342.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

in `RowDataBound` try:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    // searching through the rows
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
      if(int.Parse(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem,"Risk").ToString()) > 100)
        {
            e.Row.BackColor = Color.FromName("#FAF7DA"); // is a "new" row
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            e.Row.BackColor = Color.Yellow;

            Label l1 = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblage");
            if(Convert.ToInt32( l1.Text)>=30)
            {
                e.Row.BackColor = Color.Tomato;
            }

        }
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you added a description of your idea, not plain code.